# Using the input 'speech' tag via javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, speech-recognition

Doing this in chrome:

```
<input id='speech-this' type='text' speech />
```

Creates an input tag with a little mic. Clicking on the mic does voice recognition, like android phones search.

My question is: Is it possible to do this without the `<input>` field? I mean, the ideal thing would be a javascript object that does something like:

```
var what_i_said = chrome.Speech.listen();
```

Or something like that.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for showing me a new toy to entertain me for 3 minutes! It is very fond of interpreting whatever I say as US State names apparently.

Comment: good thing that you got entertained  :), it would be awesome to get an answer though :(

Answer (score 1):

Opera supports http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml+voice/ (see http://dev.opera.com/articles/voice/).

You could look at the WAMI toolkit. WAMI toolkit is an interesting project from MIT - http://wami.csail.mit.edu/. In their own words "WAMI: Web-Accessible Multimodal Applications. WAMI is a simple way to add speech recognition capabilities to any web page." WAMI gives you a java applet that can run in your web page to perform audio capture for speech recognition.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually way to do this with JavaScript and it's done with the Web Speech API. This allows you to quickly do voice recognition as well as speech synthesis.

Simplest example of Speech Synthesis:

```
var utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('Hello World');
window.speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
```

Simplest example of Voice Recognition:

```
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
recognition.start();
```